# What is the best method of showing a refreshing 7x7 tiled 'map' in a Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm making a Java GUI for a game which needs to show a map of the area around the player which is 7x7 'tiles' large. I have all the tiles needed as PNG images and can get them into the application no problem. But I'm unsure of the best method of making a map which could easily be refreshed from these tiles.

I am planning on using a Loop inside a Loop to print out a series of JLabels with Image icons on them in a 7X7 format. I will remove them and print the new set every time the map 'refreshes'.

However I wanted to know if there was an easier or better way of achieving this? Or if this was a good idea.

Comment: WHAT ui system?  Swing?  AWT?  GWT?  SWT?  You have to assume that we don't know what you're doing, and give us all the context.  We also need some idea of the basis on which you're going to change any of the tiles, and I can tell you that it won't be regarded as a good idea in any of these systems to refresh the whole UI because one or a few tiles have changed...

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"? How often does it refresh?

Comment: I'm sorry If I wasn't clear, I am using Swing and the entire UI doesn't refresh, just the 7x7 Map "scrolls" as the player moves, therefore refreshing every time the player moves up, down, left or right a tile. The question was more aimed at what Swing objects would be best suited for this and what Layouts would be easiest to format. I currently have a panel in my Jframe in which I would like the map to print to. I'm currently doing this by printing JLabels with image icons which correspond to a String 2D Array which represent the map.